# Determining whether $bdy(A)\subseteq A'$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $bdy(A)$ be the boundary of $A$, $A'$ be the set of all accumulation points of $A$. I'd like to know whether $bdy(A)\subseteq A'$. Perhaps it would be good to settle down some definitions first. In my textbook, $bdy(A)$ consists of points whose open balls intersect both $A$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ while an accumulation point of $A$ is a point $x$ for which any $B(x,r)\cap A\setminus\{x\}$ cannot be empty.

For now, I ***assume*** $bdy(A)\subseteq A'$ and try to confirm it. Let $x\in bdy(A)$ and fix $r>0$. I want to find an open ball $B(x,r)$ s.t. $B(x,r)\cap A\setminus\{x\}\neq\emptyset$, thus causing $x$ to fall into $A'$. If $x$ is already outside of $A$, there's nothing to do because $B(x,r)\cap A\neq\emptyset$. What if $x$ is inside of $A$? Is there anything I can do to finish the confirmation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A = \{0\}$. Then $\text{bdy}(A) = A$ but $A'=\emptyset$

Comment: Thank you. Finding a counterexample is never an easy job for me.